# Extract data from XML string in Hive Table without using XPath

Tags: sql, regex, xpath, hive, xml-parsing

I am trying to use a view to extract a string(value) from a large XML string that sits in a single column in a hive table. I need to get the associated FOO_STRING_VALUE for COMPANY_ID, SALE_IND, and CLOSING_IND.

```
    <Message>
        <Header>
            <FOO_STRING>
                <FOO_STRING_NAME>COMPANY_ID</FOO_STRING_NAME>
                <FOO_STRING_VALUE>44-1235</FOO_STRING_VALUE>
            </FOO_STRING>
            <FOO_STRING>
                <FOO_STRING_NAME>SALE_IND</FOO_STRING_NAME>
                <FOO_STRING_VALUE>Y</FOO_STRING_VALUE>
            </FOO_STRING>
            <FOO_STRING>
                <FOO_STRING_NAME>CLOSING_IND</FOO_STRING_NAME>
                <FOO_STRING_VALUE>Y</FOO_STRING_VALUE>
            </FOO_STRING>
        </Header>
    </Message>
```

The XML file can have up to 50 "FOO_STRINGS" and there is no guarantee in what order they will be in so I can not use XPATH unless I have 50 xpath_string calls for each Name/Value pair and matched them up later. I am using xpath like this .....

```
       xpath_string(xml_txt, '/Message/Header/FOO_STRING[1]/FOO_STRING_VALUE') AS String_Val_1                   
       xpath_string(xml_txt, '/Message/Header/FOO_STRING[2]/FOO_STRING_VALUE') AS String_Val_2                                                        
       xpath_string(xml_txt, '/Message/Header/FOO_STRING[3]/FOO_STRING_VALUE') AS String_Val_3
```

However, if the order changes than it doesn't work. I'm wondering if there is a quick way to get to find the `FOO_STRING_NAME` needed the and get the corresponding Value using `regexp_extract()` or some other way? I am not familiar with Regex so any help or suggestions would be helpful, Thank you a ton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *" if the order changes than it doesn't work "*

Don't use position, then.

```
xpath_string(xml_txt, '/Message/Header/FOO_STRING[FOO_STRING_NAME="COMPANY_ID"]/FOO_STRING_VALUE') AS String_Val_1                   
xpath_string(xml_txt, '/Message/Header/FOO_STRING[FOO_STRING_NAME="SALE_IND"]/FOO_STRING_VALUE') AS String_Val_2                                                        
xpath_string(xml_txt, '/Message/Header/FOO_STRING[FOO_STRING_NAME="CLOSING_IND"]/FOO_STRING_VALUE') AS String_Val_3
```

Comment: Thank you Alejandro, I wasn't aware xpath could do that.